# D3, having trouble adding new group element and line

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm in the process of visualizing a linked list.  Just doing it for fun and to learn d3.js.  I am able to create group elements for the circles (which represent a node).  But I can't figure out why a new group element is not being added after that.  I want this new group to contain the line/arrow (the .next reference representation).  I debugged through CDT the code is being executed but nothing is being added to the DOM.

```
var g = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(dataArr)
    .enter().append("g")
        .attr("transform", function() {
            if (addMethod === "headAdd") {
                return "translate(" + 50 + " ," + y + ")";
            } else {
                return "translate(" + x + " ," + y + ")";
            }
        })
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.getData(); });

    // Create a circle representing the node.
    g.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 40)
        .style("fill", "#7DC24B")
        .style("stroke", "#122A0A")
        .style("stroke-width", 5)
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .style("stroke-opacity", 0.8)
        .transition().duration(1000).style("opacity", 1);

    // Add data to the node.
    g.append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("fill", "#ffffff")
        .text(function(d) { return d.getData(); });


    // Create the "next" arrow.
    // l is the line group that will enclose the line
    // and the text.

    // This doesn't seem to be working from here below.
    var l = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(["1"])
    .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "lines")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (x + 40) + ", " + y + ")");

    l.append("line")
        .attr("x1", x + 40)
        .attr("y1", y)
        .attr("x2", x + 100)
        .attr("y2", y)
        .style("stroke", "#8EBD99")
        .style("stroke-width", 30);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ...

```
var l = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(["1"])
```

... selects the existing group elements (i.e. the one you've just created) and performs a data join with those. The enter() selection will be empty since the elements you selected were already present in the DOM. Therefore the parts after `.enter()` will not be executed and the `l` selection will be empty.

You have to make the selector more specific, like:

```
var l = svg.selectAll(".lines")
        .data(["1"])
```

The [Thinking with Joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) article does a good job in explaining the data join concepts. See also the [General Update Patterns (I,II,III)](http://bl.ocks.org/3808218) for more details about the different kind of selections you'll encounter during data joins.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Thank you! :)